# GParted LiveCD fails to start

Tags: linux-mint, virtualbox, virtual-machine, gparted

I have a VM setup in VirtualBox (LinuxMint 17.1). But I'm trying to boot to GParted so I can resize a partition. I'm using `gparted-live-0.22.0-2-amd64.iso` and it boots correctly. I've tried every option in GRUB as well as the latter menu, but I can't get past this screen:

[image: GParted Won't Start]

This screen also appears during boot, before I get to the keymap selection screen:

[image: GParted LiveCD Errors]

**[VM Configuration is here](http://pastebin.com/XkMPNgDG)**

Comment: Is this 32bit VM? Have you try with 32bit livecd?

Comment: 64-bit VM; 64-bit LiveCD. Also tried the i586 ISO.

Comment: Added VM config.

Comment: LinuxMint LiveCD boots and starts up fine. Trying to use that instead.

Comment: That worked fine - so I'm all set. Still would like to know why it wouldn't boot though.

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem and checked the "Enable EFI (special OSes only)" extended feature and it started working.

[image: VirtualBox VM settings, showing System: EFI enabled]

Comment: Had the same trouble, tried the Enable EFI and it was the same deal. strange thing was that the same image had worked thirty minutes before on a 32-bit VM

Comment: you are a life saver

Comment: This worked for me also.