# extend Disk space

Tags: hard-disk, disk-usage, fdisk

i want extend my disk space :

`#df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs           403M   17M  387M   4% /run
/dev/sda1        19G   18G  183M  99% /
tmpfs          1006M  208K 1006M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs          1006M     0 1006M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
Dropbox         465G  391G   74G  85% /media/psf/Dropbox
tmpfs           202M  8.0K  202M   1% /run/user/132
tmpfs           202M   20K  202M   1% /run/user/0`

`#fdisk -l
Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *        2048 40136703 40134656 19.1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       40138750 41940991  1802242  880M  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       40138752 41940991  1802240  880M 82 Linux swap / Solaris`

i expand VM Disk space from 20GB to 45GB

`#fdisk -l
Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *        2048 40136703 40134656 19.1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       40138750 94371839 54233090 25.9G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       40138752 94371839 54233088 25.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris`

`#df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs           403M  6.0M  397M   2% /run
/dev/sda1        19G   18G  179M 100% /
tmpfs          1006M  208K 1006M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs          1006M     0 1006M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
Dropbox         465G  391G   74G  85% /media/psf/Dropbox
tmpfs           202M  8.0K  202M   1% /run/user/132
tmpfs           202M   20K  202M   1% /run/user/0`

how Can i expand `/dev/sda1`

Comment: You first delete `/dev/sda5` and `/dev/sda2` to make room and then expand `/dev/sda1`

Comment: can tell me how ?

Answer (score 1):

Although you could [resize a filesystem with command line tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169395/how-do-i-resize-partitions-and-filesystems-on-them), I recommend to use [GParted](http://gparted.org/). You should be able to install it with your package manager, or you download the CD image, mount it to the VM and reboot to start it.

Comment: Gparted not help to me . all options is unavailable

Comment: @MehranGoudarzi You need to run it as `root`, e. g. using `sudo`. Did you do that?